# Why is the file size repeating itself?

Tags: c

I'm trying to list files and their sizes in "first" folder but I am getting weird repetition of every two files.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct dirent *dirPtr;
struct stat st;

void main()
{
    DIR * dirp;
    if((dirp=opendir("first"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("There has been an error");
    }

    while(dirPtr=readdir(dirp))
    {
        printf("%s - ", dirPtr->d_name);
        stat(dirPtr->d_name, &st);  
        printf(" file size: %lu\n", st.st_size);
    }
    closedir(dirp);
}
```

This is my output:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: `void main` -- **Raaaaaaaarrrrrrrrgggggggghhhhhhhh**

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you should probably check the return result from "stat()", and print an error # (instead of file size) if stat() fails.

Also: "opendir()" is reading files from some arbitrary directory.

Q: Does "dirPtr->d_name" contain a full filepath ... or just a filename?  In other words, are you trying to "stat()" from the wrong directory?

Comment: my guess is that stat() return -1.

Comment: just added:  
`if (stat(dirPtr->d_name, &st) == -1)  
{ 
    perror("stat");  
}`  
and my output changed to:
. -  file size: 4096   
.. -  file size: 4096 
test.c -  file size: 2566  
stat: No such file or directory  
CProg2a.doc -  file size: 2566  
stat: No such file or directory  
C Presentation.ppt -  file size: 2566

Comment: Kewl :)  So now you understand the problem.  There are several solutions, including 1) prepend the path to the filename (e.g. "strcpy (full_path, dirname); strcat (full_path, filename)", or 2) chdir() before you stat().  And ALWAYS check the return values of functions that might fail :)

Comment: hey it worked how do i come back a folder?
because i got 2 folder listings and after i done with first i assume it stays in folder 'first' now i wanna come back a level and look for folder 'second'

Comment: Call "getcwd()" to save the current directory before you "chdir()" to a different one.  Then just "chdir()" back when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically calling `stat("test.c", &st)`.  How is `stat` supposed to know what directory `test.c` is in?  I don't think it can.

I think you should try doing `stat("./first/test.c", &st)` or `stat("/full/path/to/first/test.c", &st)`.  Better yet, you should find some function like `stat` that takes a `struct dirent` as the argument, so you don't have to worry about concatenating strings.

I'll see if there is a such a function and edit my answer if I find one.

Comment: Correct, you are listing files in a directory "first" but you are doing the "stat" call as they were in current directory -- stat is actually returning an error, and the 'sizes' you are getting are just random unitialized data in the st structure.

Answer (score 1):

Every directory has at least two entries, the current directory - a single dot `.` - and the parent directory - two dots `..`